# Would it make sense to do a two-factor decomposition similar to singular-value decomposition?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

A finite-dimensional matrix $M$ can be decomposed as

$$
M = U \Sigma V^*
$$

where $U$ and $V^*$ are unitary matrices whose geometric interpretation is rotation and $\Sigma$ scaling along the orthonormal basis.   Would it be possible to decompose $M$ as just one rotation followed by one scaling

$$
M = \Sigma R
$$

?

Comment: In the second factorization you imply that $\Sigma$ is diagonal (a scaling matrix) and $R$ is a unitary matrix (that corresponds to rotation)?

Comment: Every matrix of the form $\Sigma R$ where $\Sigma$ is diagonal and $R$ is unitary has orthogonal rows, so no. But you can do it if you allow $\Sigma$ to be symmetric: see [polar decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition).

Comment: You might be interested in reading about the [QR decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition) and variants such as the LQ decomposition.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the singular-value decomposition (SVD) of the finite dimensional matrix $M$ is

$$
M = U \Sigma V^*,
$$

one can insert identity represented as the product of Hermitian matrices $I = V V^*$ in the decomposition and regroup the factors as a product of a unitary matrix and a [normal matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix)

$$
M = (U V^*) (V \Sigma V^*) = W N,
$$

where $W$ is a unitary matrix representing a rotation, and $N$ a normal matrix representing contraction and expansion along axes in an appropriate orthogonal basis that can be obtained by the rotation represented by the unitary matrix $V^*$.  Note the normal matrix $N$ is unitarily similar to the diagonal matrix $\Sigma$.

So instead of $M = \Sigma R$, one can always get decomposition of form $M = W N$ which is [polar decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition).

If $M$ is invertible, the the decomposition is unique.  This is analogues to that non-zero complex number has unique decomposition $z = r e^{i \theta}$ up to the periodicity in $\theta$.